# Can't install SDL on MinGW, getting `undefined reference to WinMain@16`

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, sdl

I'm trying to install SDL on MinGW.

I've downloaded SDL from [here](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) (the `SDL2-devel-2.0.0-mingw.tar.gz` link), then copied the contents of `SDL2-2.0.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32/{bin,include,lib}` into the matching directories in my MinGW installation.

When I try to compile any file that contains `#include ‹SDL2/SDL.h›` using `gcc test.c -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows`, GCC complains about `undefined reference to WinMain@16` and `undefined reference` to some SDL functions.

Comment: What is the prototype of your main function in test.c? It must be int (int, char **).

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SDL2-devel-2.0.0-mingw.tar.gz` contains both 32-bit libraries (`i686-w64-mingw32` directory) and 64-bit libraries (`x86_64-w64-mingw32` directory).

The error was caused by using a 64-bit version of the library with a 32-bit compiler.